# Find the Eigenvalues and Eigenfunctions for the Boundary problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I recently found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2104882/637375) answer to a similar problem I'm currently working on.
The problem is the following...

Find the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions for

$y^{\prime \prime}+\lambda y=0$

with the boundary conditions

$y^{\prime} (0)=0$ , $y^{\prime} (1)=0$

---

In the answer linked above, the Ansatz for

- $\lambda <0$ is $y(x)=C_1e^{\sqrt{\lambda} x}+C_2e^{-\sqrt{\lambda} x}$
- $\lambda >0$ is $y(x)=C_1\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x)+C_2\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x)$

But I don't really get why. Has someone got some background information/explanation why $y(x)$ must be of this form?

The case for $\lambda =0$ is clear to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to solve the characteristic polynomial $r^2+\lambda =0$ For $\lambda > 0$ and $\lambda <0$.

Comment: Sorry for the basic question but why exactly $r^2+\lambda$? It makes sense because I get the Ansatz for $y(x)$ above but is this always the characteristic polynomial I've to look for?

Comment: When you solve a differential equation with constant coefficients yes you need the polynomial characteristiic. Maybe you should read the wiki page on differential linear equations.

Comment: $y''+by'+cy=0$ has the characteristic polynomial as $r^2+br+c=0$ You find $r$ then the solution is $y=ke^{rx}$ Maybe you should read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y^{\prime \prime}+\lambda y=0$$
We suppose that the solution is on the form $y=e^{rx}$ then you get:
$$r^2e^{rx}++\lambda e^{rx}=0$$
$$e^{rx}(r^2+\lambda)=0$$
$$\implies r^2+ \lambda=0$$
Solve the characteristic polynomial. You have three cases: $\lambda >0, \lambda =0, \lambda<0$. Then the solution is:
$$ \lambda <0 \implies y=c_1e^{r_1x}+c_2e^{r_2x}$$
$$ \lambda >0 \implies y=c_1 \cos ({r_1x)}+c_2\sin (r_2x)$$
Where $r_1,r_2$ are solution of the polynomial characteristic. Apply the initial conditions you'll find the value of the constants $c_1,c_2$.

Comment: Makes sense now, thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome. The wiki page is also interesting.